# Connecting verbs without the preposition "to"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I came across this sentence:

> "Immersion programs provide precisely the type of environment that Krashen claims fosters acquisition"

in "The Teacher`s Grammar of English"- Ron Cowan, page 31.

I would like to know why these two verbs are used in such order - *"claims fosters"*?
Would not it be correct if it said *"claims to foster acquisition"*?
What are we dealing with in this case?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, Krashen claims, and "the type of environment" fosters.  It looks clunky when you pull just the verbs out of it for analysis, but the "second verb in the infinitive" is not a hard and fast rule, it's just how it often shakes out.  It might have been more clearly worded with a modal verb like "can", i.e., "claims can foster", but the verbs in this case correspond to two separable subjects.

Comment: Actually it is a rule. When one verb is followed by another, the second verb can be either in the *ing* form or infinitive.I have never seen two verbs in a sentence placed in the S - from one after another.